# How do I select 3,000 out of 10,000 files in file manager?

Tags: files, filemanager, copy, user-data

I want to select the first 3,000 files in a folder which contains 10,000 files. How do I select only the first 3,000? And if possible, how can I subsequently select the next 3,000 and then 3,000 after that?

I need to copy them into separate folders, each with 3,000 files.

Comment: Select as in highlight by mouse or some command ?

Comment: @Emmet Either. I need to copy them into separate folders.

Comment: Tasks like this are exactly why it's still useful to have and know a CLI even in the fancy-graphics age.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no easy method to do that from a stock file manager. You can do it with <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Arrow Up</kbd> (or <kbd>Arrow Down</kbd>) but you will need to select the amount of files yourself.

**Command line**:

This will copy (`cp`) 3000 files (`-n 3000`)  to /opt/ (`-t "$directory"`):

```
cd /dir/with/files/
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | head -z -n 3000 | xargs -0 -r -- cp -t "/opt/" --
```

- Change 3000 to another number if needed
- Change /opt/ to your desctination.
- Use `mv -tf` to move instead of `cp -t` when you know `cp` does what you want (the `mv` is needed to clear the 3000 files)

Comment: `mv: target './10000000.jpg' is not a directory`

This error shows up when I use the `mv` command. However it works just fine when I use the `cp` command. 

Also, is there a way to delete the first 3,000 files in the same way?

Comment: Edit - It worked just by changing the flag from `-f` to `-t` for the `mv` command.

Comment: then `tf`. f to force overwrite ;) And the cp is just to test the 1st group. mv delete the 3000 files.

Comment: You can probably omit the `--` end-of-options argument, since `find . ` will prepend `./` to every filename. You could also consider using `printf './%s\0' *` in place of the `find -maxdepth 1` command